# How to pass cookies from .NET application to Next.js app?

Tags: .net, next.js, cookies, rtk-query

My app contains client side (written in Next.js; http) and server side (.NET; https)
I am trying to do authorization, but can't properly pass the cookies from one side to another. It is important to mention, that cookies ARE saving and everything does work in boundaries of server side (using `Swagger`). So may be problem in `SameSite` policy

Here is the code of `Program.cs`:

```
const string allowLocalhost3000 = "allowLocalhost3000";

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: allowLocalhost3000,
        config =>
        {
            config
                .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials()
                .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
                .WithExposedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
        });
});

// ...

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None;
        options.LoginPath = "/auth/login";
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors(allowLocalhost3000);
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

`RTK Query` methods:

```
export const authAPI = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'authAPI',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({baseUrl: 'https://localhost:7024'}),
    endpoints: (build) => ({
        register: build.mutation<void, RegisterRequest>({
            query: (request: RegisterRequest) => ({
                url: '/auth/register',
                method: 'POST',
                body: request,
                credentials: 'include',
            }),
        }),
        login: build.mutation<void, LoginRequest>({
            query: (request: LoginRequest) => ({
                url: '/auth/login',
                method: 'POST',
                body: request,
                credentials: 'include',
            }),
        }),
        getCurrent: build.query<string, void>({
            query: () => ({
                url: '/auth/get_current',
                credentials: 'include',
            }),
        }),
    })
})
```

I can also provide you with endpoints methods, but it looks not necessary for me, as they DO work in boundaries of server side application. Would really appreciate any help with that